# convert 2 streams in one stream and map()

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

i have a array of StudentLogin where name is the key and value is value

```
"studentLogin" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "firstName_key",
            "value" : "<actual first Name value>"
        },
        {
            "name" : "lastName_key",
            "value" : "<actual last Name value>"
        },
        ....
      ]
```

i have a method which i get List of studentLogin as an input parameter,i need to check if firstName(key) and lastName(key) is present in the same index or not if yes then i need to concat the actual value of firstname and lastname from same index.

i wrote the below method but using two streams,i want to convert it into one stream.

```
  public String convertStudentLoginToFullName(List<StudentLogin> studentLogin) {
      if (null != studentLogin) {
        String firstName = studentLogin.stream()
                .filter(x -> "firstName_key".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName()))
               .map(x->x.getValue())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        String lastName = studentLogin.stream()
                .filter(x -> "lastName_key".equalsIgnoreCase(x.getName()))
                .map(x -> x.getValue())
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);
        String fullName=firstName+" "+lastName;
        return fullName;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want `<actual first Name value> <actual last Name value>`?

Comment: yes,thats correct.

Comment: why is that `studentLogin ` even a list? don't you think, an object could have represented the information better?

Comment: yea good question,think in this way,lets say student is login in into different applications in the university so in that scenario the studentLogin may have different id/pwd for all of them so created a list, makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert your list of `StudentLogin` to a `Map` first:

```
Map<String, String> studentLoginMap = studentLogin.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        StudentLogin::getName(),
        StudentLogin::getValue(),
        (old, new) -> old
    ))
```

Note that if there are multiple `StudentLogin`s with the same name, I use the merge function `(old, new) -> old` to resolve the conflict. Always use the old value matches what you did in your original code - taking the first that matches `firstName_key` and `lastName_key`.

Now, you can access the values of `studentLoginMap` and concatenate if both first and last name exist:

```
String firstName = studentLoginMap.get("firstName_key");
String lastName = studentLoginMap.get("lastName_key");
if (firstName != null && lastName != null) {
   String result = firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use method [`Collectors.toMap​(keyMapper,valueMapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) as follows:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<StudentLogin> studentLoginList = List.of(
            new StudentLogin(null, null),
            new StudentLogin("firstName_key", "<actual first Name value>"),
            new StudentLogin("lastName_key", "<actual last Name value>"));

    Map<String, String> studentLoginMap = studentLoginList.stream()
            // check if name and value are not null
            .filter(stlog -> stlog.getName() != null
                    && stlog.getValue() != null)
            // collect to map
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    StudentLogin::getName,
                    StudentLogin::getValue));

    String firstName = studentLoginMap.get("firstName_key");
    String lastName = studentLoginMap.get("lastName_key");

    if (firstName != null && lastName != null) {
        System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName);
        // <actual first Name value> <actual last Name value>
    }
}
```

```java
public static class StudentLogin {
    String name;
    String value;

    public StudentLogin(String name, String value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public String getValue() { return value; }
}
```

---

<sup>See also: [Invert a Map with redundant values to produce a multimap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540984/14838237)</sup>